# Facebook app post on user's wall low quality image

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, http-post

So I have app, which post image on user's wall. Problem is that, It automatically choose App's image (Page Tab Image 111x74) and add It on user's wall (exapanded). I need to add custom image, not app's page tab image. For now my code:

```
$photoCaption = 'Text......';
$link = ('https://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage/1555555555?sk=app_1800000000');

  # Post Data for Photos API
  $post_data = array(
      'message' => $photoCaption,
      'link' => $link,
      'caption'   => 'This is captions!'
  );

$apiResponse = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $post_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You post photos with `/me/photos`, not `/me/feed`, here´s the information you need including example code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/photos